# Ionic Scroll Issue with anchorScroll()

Tags: angularjs, scroll, ionic-framework, anchor, anchor-scroll

When I am using

```
$location.hash('idWhereAnchorShouldBePlaced');
$ionicScrollDelegate.anchorScroll();
```

in my controller for going to a specific point in my page; My page top scroll stuck and bottom scroll goes so long.
Please post if there is any fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view file I added `overflow-scroll="true"`

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true"> like below
```

and this smoothly fixed the issue.

Actually this issue is one reported [issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/508) of ionic.

I find patch answer [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/content-stuck-after-anchorscroll/776). Have a look at this also.

Comment: This works in my browser and in Android. iOS is just broken, did this worked for you on iOS?

Comment: Yes, I only tested in iPh6 and 6+. And it is working as expected.